# Simple way of checking if one of three booleans are true

Tags: c#, .net, boolean

I've tried using the following code, but as far as I can tell it only checks the first two variables.

```
if (var1 || var2 || var3)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Comment: `I can tell it only checks the first two variables`, if one of them is true, no need to check the third one  (the second is true in your case) :)

Comment: No. It first checks if var1 is true, if it's not it checks if var2 is true, if not it checkes var3. It's called short circuiting, which is exactly what you want in the question title.

Comment: OP, do you mean you only want the statement to evaluate to true if ONLY one of three is true, but not if 2 or 3 are true?

Comment: No, I'm fine with it evaluating if one or more of them is true.

Comment: Then you're already doing it the correct way.

Comment: In the question I meant, even if var3 was true it didn't appear to execute the code in the if statement. Of course it could've been me being stupid or something.

Comment: @user2263272 read the comments again...

Comment: System Down is correct. Your current if statement will evaluate to true if *any* of your inputs are true. The statement *will* execute if var3 is true, so I think it could just be you being stupid, as you said :D (just giving you a hard time)

Answer (score 3):

If you *need* to evaluate all three, you can use:

```
if (var1 | var2 | var3)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

instead. It would seem strange to have such a need, but suppose all three were properties whose getters had side effects ...

With methods it could be:

```
if (DoWork() | DoDuties() | DoFinalStuff())
{
    // At least one method returned true ("success")
}
```

All three methods are called in any case.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correctly checking for one of the three variables to be true, i.e.

```
var1 || var2 || var3
```

is true if any of var1, var2 and var3 is true. The only subtelty here is that the actual check is performed using short-circuit logic: if var1 is true, it won't bother to check var2 and var3, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the other answers already cover what you need to do but I wanted to give a better explanation of what is happening.

The `||` or `&&` operator is what is called a "short circuit" operators, if it finds conditions to meet it's needs it stops checking other elements (the first `true` it finds for `||` or the first `false` it finds for `&&`).

so in effect

```
if(var1 || var2 || var3)
   SomeAction();
```

is the same as doing

```
if(var1)
    SomeAction();
else if(var2)
    SomeAction();
else if(var3)
    SomeAction();
```

If you only use `|` instead of `||` it will evaluate all of the members before it returns the result, something similar to this

```
bool combined = var1;
combined = var2 **OR'ed with** combined; 
combined = var3 **OR'ed with** combined; 

if(combined)
    SomeAction();
```

A very useful real-world use of short circuiting is checking for null before calling a member or method. In the following example, imagine var1 is a variable that could be null and you need to perform an action when `var1.DataAvailable()` is true. For example

```
if(var1 != null && var1.DataAvailable())
{
    //do somthing with var1 when data is available
}
```

Is the same as

```
if(var1 != null)
{
    if(var1.DataAvailable())
    {
        //do somthing with var1 when data is available
    }
}
```

Because of short circuting you will never get a `NullRefrenceException` because `var1.DataAvailable()` never executes if `var1` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned, that:

`|` - binary OR
`||` - logical OR

Lets assume `a = false` `b = true` `c=false`

`a || b || c` == `true`
`a | b | c` == `0 | 1 | 0` == `1` which also has the logical "true" value.